# Need help changing background colour based on results obtained from quiz?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I'm having issues in changing the background colour of the page based on the score obtained in the quiz.

I attempted something like this:

```
var scorecolour;
if (actualchoices[q] >= 1) {
    scorecolour=document.getElementById("main");
    scorecolour.style.backgroundcolor="green"
} 
else {
    scorecolour=document.getElementById("main");
    scorecolour.style.backgroundcolor="red"
}
```

I'm pretty new to this website, if there is anything else that is needed just ask I guess :)

Thank you guys

Comment: Almost there, but Javascript is case sensitive, `backgroundcolor` is not the same as `backgroundColor`

Comment: Also extract scorecolour as a variable outside your if condition like so: `var scorecolour = document.getElementById('main');`. Then your `style.backgroundColor` would become: `scorecolour.style.backgroundColor = actualchoices[q] >= 1 ? 'green' : 'red'`

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu +1 for the re-factoring.

Answer (score 2):

Change the script

```
scorecolour.style.backgroundColor = "green"
```

Its not backgroundcolor its backgroundColor

check this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pWsq4/)

Comment: was this answer helpful?